# Undefined variable: in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i can't get variable seat in form action at `{!! Form::open(['action' => ['SeatController@book', $seat->id] , 'method' => 'POST'])!!}` to working. here is my code:

blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <br><br><br>
    <h3>From {{$bus->departdest}} to {{$bus->arrivedest}}</h3>
    <div> Date : {{$bus->date}}</div>
    <div> Boarding Time : {{$bus->depart}}</div>
    <div> Arrival Time : {{$bus->arrival}}</div>
    <div> Plate Number : {{$bus->platenum}}</div>
    <hr>

 <img src="/images/seat.jpg" height="175.5px" width="521.5px" >
 <hr>
    <div> <h3>Available Seats : {{$bus->available}} </h3></div>
    @if ($bus->available>0)
    {!! Form::open(['action' => ['SeatController@book', $seat->id] , 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
    @csrf
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="num" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Choose seat') }}</label>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select class="form-control{{ $errors->has('num') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="num">
                @foreach($seats as $seat)
                    @if ($seat->bus_id == $bus->id && $seat->status == 0)
                    <option value="{{ $seat->id }}">{{ $seat->num }}</option>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
                </select>

                @if ($errors->has('num'))
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('num') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        {{Form::hidden('_method','POST')}}
        {{Form::submit('Confirm', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
        <a href="/search" class="btn btn-primary"> Cancel</a>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
    @else
    <div> No available ticket </div>
    <a href="/search" class="btn btn-primary"> Cancel</a>
    @endif

@endsection
```

BusController.php:

```
    public function show($id){
    $bus = Bus::find($id);
    $user = Auth::user();
    $seats = Seat::all();
    return view('showseat')->with(compact('bus', 'user', 'seats'));
}
```

Comment: You are passing `seats` to the view, and you use `seat`. Do you iterate over the `seats` and make a form for each seat? Can you show the full view?

Comment: Yes i do iterate the 'seats' and trying to get 'seat->id' from the selected options of the iteration. Full view is nothing really different. i'll show it anyway

Comment: You cannot use `$seat` outside of the loop..

Answer (score 0):

You might need to book a seat on the Bus? So here:

```
['SeatController@book', $seat->id]
```

Should be:

```
['SeatController@book', $bus->id]
```

You cannot use `$seat` there as you are passing `$seats` to the view, and you iterate to show the seat number in a select element.

Then in your `book` function you can still get the seat number using

```
$request->num // or request('num')
```

As `num` is the `name` attribute of your select field for the seat number.

Comment: i'm aware of $bus->id, but i wanted to know how to pass seat id that chosen from list of the form?